# ng-repeat orderBy not working with Boolean?

Tags: angularjs

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        foo: 'bar',
        is_boolean: false    
    },
    {
        foo: 'sheep',
        is_boolean: false    
    },
    {
        foo: 'i am first!',
        is_boolean: true    
    },
    {
        foo: 'bye',
        is_boolean: false   
    },
]
```

That I wanna sort by the `is_boolean` in a ng-repeat, but it's not working. For some reason angular doesnt recongize the boolean? 
How to fix it. Because I want the booleans that are true shown first. Now I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foobars | orderBy: 'is_boolean'">
```

Comment: Try orderBy:'is_boolean':true

Comment: I don't know why it is marked as duplicate because I tried the post that they say it is a duplicate off but that one doesn't work at all.

Comment: true! same here. it stil couldnt figure it out so i changed it serverside with the json.